# Go mongo-driver mtest, FindOne doesn't return correct result based on given filter

Tags: mongodb, go, mocking, mongo-driver

I have a function which should return based on filter from mongodb a `org`, which in reality works fine.

```golang
func (m *MongoSysService) GetOrg(org string) (types.Org, error) {
    var data types.Org
    if err := m.org.FindOne(context.Background(), bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: org}}).Decode(&data); err != nil {
        return types.Org{}, err
    }
    return data, nil
}
```

But then I try to mock it using `mtest` and what happens is that it always returns 1st result `org1`, no matter how I tried, can't figure out what's wrong.

```golang
func TestMongoSysService_GetOrg(t *testing.T) {
    mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

    mt.Run("success", func(mt *mtest.T) {
        mongoDB.org = mt.Coll

        first := mtest.CreateCursorResponse(1, "foo.bar", mtest.FirstBatch, bson.D{
            {Key: "_id", Value: "org1"},
            {Key: "name", Value: "org1"},
            {Key: "api", Value: "key1"},
        })

        second := mtest.CreateCursorResponse(2, "foo.bar", mtest.NextBatch, bson.D{
            {Key: "_id", Value: "org2"},
            {Key: "name", Value: "org2"},
            {Key: "api", Value: "key2"},
        })

        third := mtest.CreateCursorResponse(3, "foo.bar", mtest.NextBatch, bson.D{
            {Key: "_id", Value: "org3"},
            {Key: "name", Value: "org3"},
            {Key: "api", Value: "key3"},
        })

        killCursors := mtest.CreateCursorResponse(0, "foo.bar", mtest.NextBatch)

        mt.AddMockResponses(first, second, third, killCursors)

        result, err := mongoDB.GetOrg("org2")
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
        if result.Name != "org2" || result.GoogleAPIKey != "key2" {
            t.Errorf("Expected %s and %s, got %s and %s", "org2", "key2", result.Name, result.GoogleAPIKey)
        }
    })
}
```

Using the same test case I tried to use `Find` on `cursor` to find all records, it works in mock, I get all 3 records when mocking it on `Find`.

What could be the issue here?

I'm using `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.5.4` and `go1.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how a mock works - you're not saying "here's the data, now act like a database", you are saying "here's how to act like a database".  When you have

```
first := mtest.CreateCursorResponse(1, "foo.bar", mtest.FirstBatch, bson.D{
    {Key: "_id", Value: "org1"},
    {Key: "name", Value: "org1"},
    {Key: "api", Value: "key1"},
})
```

You are saying "the first thing we get back from the collection will be `org1`."  You are *not* saying "there is some data called `org1` and send it back if the query matches."

If you want `org2` to be the response, then you need to tell it to send back `org2` as the first response.

Comment: Aha, makes sence, I think that I started good with tests but then on this test case I tried to use mock as database, well now its clear, thank you for the clarification!